# other way than using if-condition

Tags: python, if-statement

im sitting on a code were I want to analyse data from a Racetrack. Right now im trying to figure out how to getting the winner. I have 4 cars and have an Lapcounter from each car and there best and last time.

My first idea is this one:

```
winnerlist.extend((Lapcounter1,Lapcounter2,Lapcounter3,Lapcounter4))
winnerlist.sort()

if (winnerlist[-1] == Lapcounter1):
   print("Car 1 got first")
#same for Car2,3,4

if (winnerlist[3] == Lapcounter1:
   print("Car 1 is second")
#and so on for third and fourth place
```

And this works only if there have all different Laps. If some have the same there would be come so many more if.

It would be great if somebody knows a better way to do it :)

im done it with a list and without. But still have many if's

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what programming language you are using. Have you tried using a `switch` statement - assuming it's supported in the chosen programming language

Comment: What is the decision in case two or more laps are equal ?

Comment: in this case I want to wait until the first one finish. But that's not the main problem I have right now..to this I get after

Answer (score 0):

```
rank= ("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
for k in range(len(winnerlist)):
    print("Car", k+1, "is", rank[sum(Lap < winnerlist[k] for Lap in winnerlist)])
```